# How to disable CTRL + mouse Left Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse Left Click event on links. I tried with keypress event but it doesn't work:

```
$('a').keypress(function (e){  
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYxUE/34/)</kbd>

Comment: By CTRL + left click you mean opening the context menu? On Windows, that would be the same a clicking the right mouse button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect control+click in Javascript from an onclick div attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190455/how-to-detect-controlclick-in-javascript-from-an-onclick-div-attribute)

Comment: It is never a good idee, to change the human expected behavior.

Comment: I specifically searched for these terms in order to make everyone out there who thinks this is a good idea *an appeal*: **Please, please, don't do this.** Seriously. For the love of God. Don't. do. this.

Comment: ...On why (not): HTML hyperlinks are meant to *redirect* the user to some other content, and how it's done is browser's problem (and users'). **If you provide me a hyperlink which doesn't open in a new tab if I control+click it, I will find a way around that, and get pissed at you.**

Comment: FWIW, questions like this (and the answers) can be helpful insomuch as they help debug things or override things when such functionality does happen to occur inadvertently or in other people's code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code that you have disables <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click, you would use the `click` event:

```
$('a').click(function (e){  
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WYxUE/45/

Note: Actually disabling ctrl+click would normally not be a good idea, and not very effective. In windows it's used to open the page in a new tab, and if that is disabled you can just use shift+click to open it in a new window instead, or right click and choose *Open link in new tab*.

Comment: "if that is disabled you can"... Also, right-click -> *copy link address* and then Control+T and Control+V, or use a Greasemonkey script, or... well, just don't rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

The full code is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script>

$(window).load(function(){

    // Disable CTRL Mouse Click    
    $('a').click(function (e){  
      if (e.ctrlKey) {
        return false;
      }
    })

    // Disable SHIFT Mouse Click    
    $('a').click(function (e){  
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        return false;
      }
    })

})

</script>
```