# capture command+click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to capture on anchor tag follwing things.

1. control + click event in JavaScript on windows / linux.
2. command + click event in JavaScript on mac os.

I used

```
\ <a onmousedown="isKeyPressed(event); return true;"> Click </a>

function isKeyPressed(event) {       
   if (event.shiftKey == 1) {
      alert('success')
    }        
}
```

In windows and linux OS this code runs but do not on MAC. 
Basically I need to block control+click on anchor tag. so they can be blocked.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect control+click in Javascript from an onclick div attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190455/how-to-detect-controlclick-in-javascript-from-an-onclick-div-attribute)

Comment: Do It runs on mac pc also ?