# JavaScript or jquery capture ctrl+left click event only

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Using JavaScript or jquery i want to capture only ctrl+left mouse click event only to show a popup. Want to capture only this combination anything else with ctrl key should not be fired.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect control+click in Javascript from an onclick div attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190455/how-to-detect-controlclick-in-javascript-from-an-onclick-div-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

The `click` event has a `ctrlKey` property. If it's `true` the ctrl-key is being pressed. Example:

```html
<button id="mybutton">click me + ctrl</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert(event.ctrlKey ? "ctrl key pressed" : "ctrl key not pressed");
});
</script>
```

Comment: OK. Will try & update. I guess these code will be fired even if i press ctrl+shift+left mouse click?

Comment: you can check ctrlKey, shiftKey and altKey

Comment: tried the above code but it gets fired even if i use ctrl + shift + left mouse click. I just want ctrl + click event not any other combination with ctrl.

Answer (score 2):

Capture the click event and check if ctrl is down. easy!

```
$("#div").click(function(event) {
 if (event.ctrlKey) {
   // ctrl + click is pressed
 }
});
```

Comment: tried the above code but it gets fired if i use ctrl + shift + left mouse click. I just want ctrl + click event not any other combination with ctrl.