# Custom show title when hold ctrl button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a custom title show.

**Example:**
At first if the mouse is over title, the title doesn't show, then if I press and hold CTRL button and mouse over title, it will appear.

The question here is how can I do that ?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial site. It's for if you have a specific question about some code you have. This is more of a question for Google.

Comment: @Scott Marcus the thing is that i didn't find anything and i don't know how to do it...

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but it doesn't change what the purpose of Stack Overflow is or how it works. This simply isn't the place for this kind of question. You haven't posted any code? However, when I search Google for ["how to detect control key being pressed in javascript"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+detect+control+key+being+pressed+in+javascript&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS761US761&oq=how+to+detect+control+key+being+pressed+in+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1294j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I see quite a few helpful links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with custom title, css and mouseover and mouseout events.

```js
$("p").mouseover(function(evt) {
  if(evt.ctrlKey){
    console.log("test")
    var title = $(this).attr("t-hide");
    $(this).removeAttr("t-hide").attr('data-title', title);
  }
}).mouseout(function() {  
  var title = $(this).attr("data-title");
  $(this).removeAttr("data-title").attr('t-hide', title);
});
```

```css
p:hover {
  position: relative;
}
p[data-title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
  background: #e4e4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p t-hide="Title Custom"> test </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

> **note:** I do not recommend default title, when the mouse is over and you press some key the title is hidden...

Comment: `<p t-hide="...">...</p>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: @Scott Marcus why it isn't valid HTML?

Comment: `t-hide` is not a valid attribute.

Comment: Also, please do not link to 3rd party sites just so we can run your code. Those links can die over time. Just include a "code snippet" (as I've done via my edit) and the code will be executable right here.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with keyup and down feature (for ctrl its 17) and also mouse over feature and simply alter css using jQuery.
Here is a relevant link -- [How to detect control+click in Javascript from an onclick div attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190455/how-to-detect-controlclick-in-javascript-from-an-onclick-div-attribute)

Comment: Please don't supply answers to bad questions. It just encourages more of the same. And really, this isn't an answer. It should be a comment.